# libxml/xmlversion.h file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using Xcode 5.0.1.
I have "libxml2.dylib" under the following path.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/lib
```

This path is set in my project HEADER SEARCH PATHS.
I have included this libxml2.dylib library in Xcode project.

When I build xcode project, it is throwing error as

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h:17:10: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found
```

I also tried setting `/usr/include/libxml2` but in this case it is showing linker error as `library not found for -lxml2`

It may be a repeating question, but my issue is strange, whatever the solution is mentioned in internet, nothing works.
Could someone advise me to fix this ?